# Is the Mobius Inversion Theorem an if and only if?

Tags: number-theory

The Mobius inversion theorem was presented to me as follows:

Given $F: \mathbb{z}_{>0} \longrightarrow \mathbb{c}$ where $F(n) = \sum_{d\mid n} f(n)$ then $f(n) = \sum_{d\mid n} F(n) \cdot \mu(n/d)$. My question, does the converse apply? (Given $f(n): \mathbb{z}_{>0}\longrightarrow \mathbb{c}$ with $f(n) = \sum_{d\mid n} F(n) \cdot \mu(n/d)$ do we get for free a function $F(n) = \sum_{d\mid n} f(n)$?

I don't see what would go wrong in the proof but I'd love verification.

On a further note, if this is valid, are there common number theoretic results that use such a formation? Why or why not?

Thanks

Comment: Look up [Dirichlet convolutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution).

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for - thanks. In practice, are there further "tricks" that you can play with the dirschelcht product? Or is mobius inversion the main practical use of the above.